# Using maximum entropy principle for joint probability estimation

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, st.statistics, entropy

Let $X_1, \dots, X_n, Y$ be random variables, each taking values in $\{0,1\}$. Assume that we are interested in estimating, for each $v=(v_1,\dots,v_n)\in \{0,1\}^n$, the probability
$$
p(v) = P[Y=1|X_1=v_1,\dots,X_n=v_n].
$$
If we have no information at all about the distribution of random vector $(X_1, \dots, X_n, Y)$, the best we can do is to assume that all $2^{n+1}$ possible values of it are equally likely, which implies that $p(v)=1/2$ for all $v$. The formal justification of this is maximal entropy principle: the uniform distribution in $\{0,1\}^{n+1}$ has the highest Shannon entropy among all distributions with the same support.

Now assume that we know the probability $P[Y=1]$, the conditional probabilities $P[Y=1|X_i]$ for all $i$, and, more generally, for some (but not all) subsets $S=\{i_1,\dots,i_k\} \subset \{1,\dots,n\}$ and $u=(u_1,\dots,u_k)\in \{0,1\}^k$, we know that
$$
P[Y=1 | X_{i_1}=u_1, \dots, X_{i_k}=u_k] = p(S,u)
$$
where $p(S,u)$ are some given numbers. To estimate $p(v)$ with this information, it would be logical to find the distribution of random vector $(X_1, \dots, X_n, Y)$ consistent with this information but as uncertain as possible otherwise. This can be formalized as finding the maximal entropy distribution under the given set of constraints.

Now, the questions are: is this a well-known approach explained in the literature? If yes, what are the references and the best key words to find the method? Are there explicit formulas and/or efficient algorithms for finding maximal entropy distributions with this type of constraints? I am ok if we impose some extra (natural) assumptions.

Finally, if this maximal entropy approach is difficult to implement, what are the other models for estimating $p(v)$ using the information in the form as above?

Comment: The jargon for this is the "principle of minimum discrimination information", where instead of maximizing entropy one minimizes the KL divergence from a prior; if the prior is uniform then this recovers the principle of maximum entropy. (In engineering, the jargon is "principle of minimum cross entropy", noting that cross entropy differs from KL-divergence by a constant for these purposes.) There are explicit formulas for this stuff, often obtained via Lagrange multipliers, and there are also some good Python libraries out there for doing numerical calculations.

Comment: Searching for “maximum entropy copula” gets a bunch of relevant results, often with hydrological applications: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=maximum+entropy+copula